# NSURL fatal Error

Tags: swift, nsurl

I try to make link to waze in Swift after i insert the url i get a fatal error.

**My code**:

```
let newName:String = closest.name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "&", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    print(closest.name)
    print(newName)
    let url:String = "waze://?q=\(newName)"

    print(url)

    let navAdd: NSURL? = NSURL(string:url)// here is the error
    let wazeApp: NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!
    print(navAdd)
    if(true){
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(navAdd!)
    }else{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(wazeApp!)
    }
```

and the error is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: On what line is the error happening?

Comment: let navAdd: NSURL? = NSURL(string:url)// here is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unwrapped an optional with out checking if its not nil.

```
if let navAdd = NSURL(string:url) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(navAdd)   
} else if let wazeApp = NSURL(string:"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106"){
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(wazeApp)
} else {print("Url not found")}
```

Comment: but this is not open the wake app the address waze://?q=חוף&פלמחים need to open the wake app if it's install on my phone